# TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable, when reading a text file

Tags: python, boolean, text-files, typeerror

I'm busy with a Uni project where I need to read text files and ten populate a table with their information. It was working fine last week when I first coded it. Now however, when I try to run it, I get the TypeError: bool, it occurs in my for loop, when I read_ln from the text file, the code is :

```
from sqlite3 import *
from webbrowser import *

    #retrieve a text file
    while inc != len(categories):
        file_open = open(categories[inc]+'.txt','U')
    #assign the category
        category = categories[inc]
    #run the loop to populate the table popularity
        for each_ln in file_open:
    #assign the variables.
            tab_index = each_ln.find('\t')
            PersonNumber = each_ln[0:tab_index]
            value = each_ln[tab_index + 1:len(each_ln)]
    #populate the database.        
            TH2_db.execute("INSERT INTO popularity VALUES (?,?,?)" \
                           , (PersonNumber, category, value))
    #increment to move onto the next textfile        
        inc = inc + 1
```

Comment: Please restrict the code to the essentials of your problem.

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question; (full) error information is useful for analysing.

Comment: When restricting the code, make sure it is still runnable. See [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, and sorry, It's my first time using Stack, I'm trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statements `from webbrowser import *` at the top of your module imports the `webbrowser.open` function (which opens a new browser window), shadowing the builtin `open` function (that opens files) which you were intending to call in your later code. `webbrowser.open` returns a Boolean value, rather than a file object, which is what the exception is about.

To fix this, change the import. Either use `import webbrowser` and qualify the places you use the  module (e.g. `webbrowser.get()` or whatever you're using it for), or import just the specific names that you know you will need (e.g. `from webbrowser import get`).

Importing with a wildcard is not generally a good idea unless the module you're doing it on is specifically designed for it. This issue shows exactly why.

Comment: Yes, thank you I just realized this while trying to re-figure out what the problem might be, further down, later on I wanted to open a html file and write to it, then open it in a webrowser, hence the import.